# Online user input into R script

Tags: html, r

I am an R programmer who unfortunately has no experience in web development or anything related, so this could be a very basic question.

I would like to know whether it's possible to create a website where user input triggers some piece of R code to run. Let's use a trivial example:

- I have a .txt file on my local device.
- If a user visited my website, he would be able to input a number and click a "send" button.
- The user should receive the sum of his input and the number stored on my text file. Then, the number in the text file should be replaced by the user's input. This means, something like this should run:

```r
 my_number <- read.txt(my_file.txt)
 write.txt(user_input, file="my_file.txt")
 output <- my_number + user_input
```

My question is, how can I tell R what the desired value for `user_input` is, and how can I let my website print the `output`.

**NOTE:** I tried to use the title "Can a website trigger R code execution?", but for some reason that is an inappropriate title!

Comment: Hi, try to use `shiny`: https://shiny.rstudio.com/ This is exactly what you need